# Flash AS3 Need help handling animations by script

Tags: actionscript-3, animation

Im trying to get a better solution for animating images like fade in slide to another location bump to another location fade out , bring in a new image, fade in, teleport to other location, let it fall down, slide out.

im in a learning progress of getting advanced with classes and my setup is like the following:

1 imgSheet, 1 tweenclass, 1 displayclass, 1 timerclass

so the display creates holderSprites, creates a bitmap out of the imagesheet and places it in the currentholderSprite, than the displayclass activates a animation function that animates the holder by triggering timers and tweens in those classes.

i understand using a timeline would be a easyer solution but this is for script learning purpose.

**now my question is:** Are there better solutions to handle this kind of animations and data passing other than using switch statements for everything. for example  could i pass a tweenvar and timervar to the classes?
if i did so how do i have to handle that variables change them and recall the functions so it becomes a animation?

simple example in script:

i send this to the bitmap creater:

```
     var rCutKongregate:Rectangle=new Rectangle(0,0,400,400);
```

```
the bitmap creater makes it a bitmap and places it in a sprite:
```

```
    public function displayImage(rn:Rectangle, o:Object):void
    { 
                            var imgSourceFile:BitmapData=new spriteSheet  ;
                var imgHolderData=new BitmapData(400,400,true,0x666666);
                var rCut:Rectangle=rn;
                var pCut:Point=new Point(0,0);
                imgHolderData.copyPixels(imgSourceFile, rCut, pCut);
                var imgHolder:Bitmap=new Bitmap(imgHolderData);

                           currentTempSprite.addChild(imgHolder);
                          }
```

```
this is how the animation triggers timers/tweens
```

```
    switch (loopNumber)
                {
                    case 2 : timersHandling("07"); break;
                    case 4 : tweensHandling("04"); break;
                }

    public function tweenHandling(s:String)
            {
                switch (s) {

                    case "01" :var sFOTween:Tween=new Tween(object,"alpha",
    Strong.easeInOut,1,0,2,true); trace("tween1 started");break;
                    case "02" :var sFITween:Tween=new Tween(object,"alpha",
    Strong.easeInOut,0,1,2,true); trace("tween2 started");break;

    public function timersHandling(s:String)
            {           
                var timer01:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
                var timer02:Timer = new Timer(2000, 1);
    var timers:Array = new Array();
                timers.push({Object:timer01, name:"timer01"});
                timers.push({Object:timer02, name:"timer02"});
    switch (s) {

                    case "01" : timer01.start(); break;
                    case "02" : timer02.start(); break;
```

well as you might understand making animations manualy by triggering functions in such a way is prob the most amature way you could do it so help will be welcome.

Comment: Why don't you try greensock framework. It's better than inbuilt animation and also had lot of options to timing the animation. here is the link http://greensock.com/gsap-as

Answer (score 0):

"Can you pass a tweenvar and a timervar to classes?" - yes, and you should make so that you don't have to track either variable after assignment. "Using a timeline could be an easier solution" - no, although for self-contained objects (that don't contain controls, referenced parts and code) a timeline animation is acceptable. And third, you are hardcoding too much in your code. You can instead use an array of them tweens, triggering and eliminating them as necessary. Indeed, you might want to look at any tween framework, Greensock, TweenMax, TweenIO and probably there are others, they have source code available for study and use, so you can find out how are they working inside.

Comment: using something like a build in framework or api is ofc a solution but as noted above this project is for learning purposes, i like to increase my skills by building things myself without external resources. Vesper, any chance you have a example of what you mean with  "yes, and you should make so that you don't have to track either variable after assignment."

Comment: If you want something done all by yourself, you have to plan ahead a bit. What should the program need of your tween engine? What objects and parameters it should accept? Then design the internal structure of your engine, where should it store temporary data, how should it manage supplied objects, etc. What do I mean - I mean copy properties of a supplied object, if you don't want to track changes, or link the supplied object if you want to track changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear exactly what you want to see happen but this can probably be done very simply with the greensock tween classes.

see: http://greensock.com/tweenmax